# How to select elements without classnames using selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following `CSS`:

```
<div aria-label="Timeline" class="some-class">
  <div style ="position: relative; min-height:1300px;">
    <div class="some-div" />
    <div class="some-div" />
    <div class="some-div" />
    //etc
```

I need to select the second div so I can iterate the children. I currently use `[aria-label="Timeline"]` to select its parent element but how can I select `<div style ="position: relative; min-height:1300px;">` if it doesn't have a classname?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[aria-label="Timeline"] > div {
  position: relative; 
  min-height: 1300px;
}
```

The arrow means that div should be the direct child of [aria-label="Timeline"]

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators